# Como abrir uma nova tela através de um Button ? (O Button está dentro de um PopUp)

Tags: java, android, popup

```java
package com.example.ConsultoriaRuiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.ConsultoriaRuiz.ui.home.HomeFragment;
import com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.net.URI;

public class Sobre extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private Button btnreceita, btndespesa;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sobre);
        Button btnreceita = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreceita);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        btndespesa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sobre.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // NÃO DÁ ERRO ALGUM, MAS O BUTTON NÃO CHAMA A PRÓXIMA TELA
                // O BUTTON ESTÁ DENTRO DE UM POPUP
            }
        });

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

    }
}
```

Comment: No seu código compartilhado o `btndespesa` nem recebe um valor. Você compartilhou o código incompleto ou simplesmente esqueceu de usar `findViewById` para o `btndespesa`?

Comment: Possui o valor, não compartilhei, amigo...

Comment: Nenhum dos button executam a função determinada, há alguma diferença ? Por estarem dentro de PopUp

Comment: Não sei o que você quer dizer com Popup, mas o `findViewById` do `Sobre` só irá encontrar elementos que estão em `R.layout.activity_sobre`. Se os seus botões estiverem nesse layout, serão encontrados, caso contrário não serão.

Comment: Todos os botões estão no Layout e instanciados, PopUp é basicamente um dialog fragment

Comment: Ele não dá erro algum, executa e abre o APP normalmente, só não executa a ação dos buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, não entendi por que você esta chamando a sua própria Activity sendo quela já esta ativa.
A função intent serve para abrir uma nova atividade, exemplo:

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

O correto, seria:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sobre.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Onde você passaria dentro dos parentes o contexto da aplicação, no caso `getApplicationContext()` e o destino, como: destino.class;

Você colocou a mesma activity que está o botão como destino, por isso não vai funcionar mesmo.